# Volume of a solid whose vertical cross section is perpendicular to the base

Tags: calculus

A solid has a base bounded by $y=x^{2}$ and $y=4$. Find its volume given that every vertical cross section perpendicular to the base and parallel to the $x$-axis is an equilateral triangle.

My solution goes as follows: 
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \int_{-2}^{2} \left(x^{2} -4 \right)^2 \; dy \approx 14.7$$

I just need to know if my answer here is correct, when we say "perpendicular to the base" does that mean perpendicular to the $y$-axis?

Comment: perpendicular to the base means perpendicular to the section of the x-y plane bound by the two given curves.  We're talking about a solid (3-D) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the right answer, let's follow the comment from @amWhy. Draw the $x$ and $y$ axes on a piece of paper. Then draw the parabola $y=x^2$ and the line $y=4$. Now a cross section perpendicular to the base is any plane perpendicular to your piece of paper. In the problem they specifically talk about cross section parallel to the $x$ axis. So draw a line parallel to $x$ on the paper (constant $y$), intersecting the parabola. Now imagine the plane perpendicular to the paper along this line. It will intersect the parabola at $$x=\pm\sqrt y$$
This will be the bottom of the equilateral triangle. So the area of the triangle is $$A(y)=\frac 12\frac{\sqrt 3}2 (2\sqrt y)^2$$
Then the volume will be $$V=\int_0^4 A(y)dy=\sqrt 3\int_0^4ydy$$

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much, it made SO MUCH more sense to me when I drew it and tried to imagine it.